# Submitting form in capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have a form I'm testing with Capybara. Once I have my spec fill in all the fields in the form, I have it hit the submit button. On submit, I'm getting an error that says the following:

```
Failure/Error: click_button 'Submit Contact Information'
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"information_forms", :lender_id=>"2293"} missing required keys: []
```

The form code looks like the following:

```
<%= form_for @lenderinformationform, url: lender_lender_information_form_path(@user) do |f| %>
    <%= f.submit "Submit Contact Information", 'data-disable-with' => "Please wait..", :class => "btn-u btn-u btn-block margin-bottom-20", :type => "submit", :id => "skyformbutton" %>
<% end %>
```

The Spec:

```
before :each do
  user = FactoryGirl.create(:lender, :email => "1234@gmail.com")
  login_as(user)
end

it "completes lender information form" do
  click_button 'Submit Contact Information'
end
```

I can complete this form in my browser when I do it manually, however there seems to be an issue with the submit button in my capybara spec.

Comment: Can you edit to include your `information_forms` controller code? Also, why do you say you "fill in all of the fields on the form" when there don't seem to be any here?

Comment: From the id of skyformbutton - is it safe to assume you are using skyform and angularjs?  If so are you running the test using a JS capable driver (not rack-test), and are you sure you don't have any JS errors?  In development mode JS files are not concatenated together which means an error in 1 will only stop execution of the rest of that file.  In test mode they get concatenated and therefore an error can stop execution of all the following files.  This means your page may not be having the angularjs stuff initialized fully and just defaulting to standard form behavior